# Change encoding of extracted text using PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage?

Tags: itext

I want to extract some text using itextsharp but instead of 'Köln' I get 'K\0ln', instead of 'Währung' I get 'W\0hrung' (and more examples), which means both 'ä' and 'ö' gets replaced by '\0'.
How do I set the encoding?

```
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sSourceFileName))
        {
            PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
            string sText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, iPageFilter, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
        }
```

Comment: You'll need to supply the input document, because there's a decent chance that there is a fundamental problem with that document.

Comment: If I view it in foxit or adobe or even a browser it gets rendered fine.
i can't upload the document though, because it's confidential. Any other way to check if there is a fundamental problem with the document? The header looks that way when I open it with an editor:
`%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
5 0 obj
<<
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Name /Im0
/Width 3507
/Height 2480
/BitsPerComponent 8
/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
/Filter /DCTDecode
/Length 4 0 R
>>
stream`

Comment: If you are an iText customer then you can upload it to our Jira and our support team will treat your document in a confidential way. If your legal team requests it then a Non-Disclosure Agreement is certainly possible.

Comment: *"If I view it in foxit or adobe or even a browser it gets rendered fine."* - What happens if you copy&paste from those viewers?

Comment: @mkl: Good point - I can't mark the text there. Somehow itextsharp can still get some text.

Comment: In that case the problem clearly is the PDF. Without inspecting it I have no way of knowing whether it still can be salvaged or not.

Comment: Please consider purchasing a commercial license for your use of iText. I hope that you understand that "open source" and "confidential" don't really match well. If you're working in a closed source, proprietary environment with confidential documents, you may not be allowed to use iText for free under the AGPL. If you are conforming to the rules of the AGPL, it may still make sense to purchase a commercial license due to the nature of your work: to give your customer the peace of mind regarding licensing of the software you're developing.